# Как отключить скрол контента

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Друзья, прошу сразу обратить внимание на сайт:
[Сайт](http://m.%D0%BC%D1%86%D1%83%D0%BD.%D1%80%D1%84)

Я делаю мобильную версию. В хедере есть кнопка открытия меню.
Как только я на нее нажимаю, контент выдвигается и становится видна левая панель. Для того что бы контент не скролился я отключаю скроллинг функцией Scroll

Вот она:

```
function Scroll(str)
    {
      var scrollPosition = [
        self.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft,
        self.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop  || document.body.scrollTop
      ];

      if(str=="off")
      {
        var html = jQuery("html");
        html.data("scroll-position", scrollPosition);
        html.data("previous-overflow", html.css("overflow"));
        html.css("overflow", "hidden");
        window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0][1], scrollPosition[1][0]);
        $(".contentlayer").bind("touchmove", function(e){e.preventDefault()});
      }
      else
      {
        var html = jQuery("html");
        var scrollPosition = html.data("scroll-position");
        html.css("overflow", html.data("previous-overflow"));
        window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
        $(".contentlayer").unbind("touchmove");
      }
    }
```

Если контент на сайте **НЕ БЫЛ** прокручен, то есть мы находимся на позиции 0 0 то все работает нормально. Если же прокрутить контент немного вниз, **а затем нажать на кнопку меню**, то происходят скачки. Сначало моментальный подьем в точку 0 0 а затем выдвигание панели и кривая анимация. Как только мы жмем на меню еще раз, то блок с контентом задвигается и устанавливается позиция та которая была.

ВОПРОС: как убрать скачек? Я хочу что бы при прокрутке контента, и нажатия на кнопку меню блок с контентом не поднимался в 0 0, а просто остался так как есть, но скрол при этом был отключен.

Все css и функции можно просмотреть в принципе в исходном коде страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Я для себя выбрал следующий вариант решения данной проблемы:

1. Для `body` задаем:

   ```
   body {
     overflow-x:hidden;
     overflow-y:auto;
   }
   ```
2. Добавляем новый класс для `body`, например, `.fixed`:

   ```
   body.fixed {  
     overflow:hidden;
   }
   ```
3. При открытии/закрытии меню добавляем/удаляем у `body` класс
   `.fixed`. Например, так:

   ```
   $('.menu').on('click',function() {
     $('body').toggleClass('fixed');
   });
   ```

Comment: Простите, а вы можете помочь еще разобраться, я уже вроде как сделал то что хотел, теперь контент уже остается на том месте что и был если его проскролили, но теперь у меня при открывании и отрабатывании анимации передергивается зеленая панель. никак не могу понять в чем собственно дело. уже мучаюсь целый день никакого результата

Comment: @iSeeDev что значит передергивается?

Comment: Если можно, попробуйте зайти на сайт с телефона, затем спуститесь в низ главной страницы и попробуйте открыть меню. вы увидите всю проблему, с которой я мучаюсь

Comment: @iSeeDev крайне не советую при раскрытии меню выставлять контенту `position:fixed`. На личном опыте убедился, что при такой варианте на телефонах сильно глючит анимацию. Попробуйте применить мой способ и увидите разнице